# Dash rangeslider 'Input' is not iterbale

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am working on a Dash app where I need to change the size of imported data, to do that I need to use RangeSlider with left bound being the start of the data and the right one being end.
This is my RangeSlider function:

```
dcc.RangeSlider(
            id='my-slider',
            min=0,
            max=12,
            step=1,
            value=[8, 12],
        ),
```

And this is my callback function:

```
@yield_model_app.callback(Output("plot_static", "figure"), Input("my_slider", "value"))
def update_comparison_graf(date_chosen):
    return draw_comparison_graph(date_chosen[0], date_chosen[1])
```

However this throws an error: `TypeError: 'Input' object is not iterable`
Why is this happening? According to Dash, the output should be a list of 2 values `[left_bound, right_bound]` so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback should look like this:

```py
@yield_model_app.callback(Output("plot_static", "figure"), [Input("my_slider", "value")])
def update_comparison_graf(date_chosen):
    return draw_comparison_graph(date_chosen[0], date_chosen[1])
```

Note how the `Input` is wrapped in square brackets, making it a list of length 1 in this case.